# Network Manager doesnt find wireless network

Tags: debian, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

I'm using Debian 9 Stretch, i provided my wifi ssid and pass on the installing process, and it works, but NetworkManager doesn't work properly finding another wifi.

This is my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file.

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

And this, my `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug wlp1s0
#if something dies delete this line
#auto wlp1s0 
iface wlp1s0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid .XT1040
    wpa-psk  ********
```

This is my `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` file.

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wheel
update_config=1
```

Comment: Does NM find (and use) the WiFi that you specified at installation time?

Comment: Yes, all interfaces were detected and working, in fact i was able to scan directly from terminal

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution

```
allow-hotplug wlp1s0
```

Is the same than

```
auto wlp1s0
```

So, i just commented it and its working!